# Get the position of a JSON element in a GSON generated String

Tags: java, json, string, gson

Suppose I have a `JsonElement` and a JSON string that I generated with `Gson.toJson(...)`. Is it possible to determine the location of the JsonElement within the string? In other words, can GSON find the string position of the element in the generated JSON code that corresponds to a `JsonElement` that was included in the JSON being generated? If so, how?

Comment: The question is: What for?!

Comment: I'm not sure if you're asking about actual index in the String, or structural position. If it's the latter, [json-path](https://code.google.com/p/json-path/) might be useful - I'm not sure if it can find elements like you are trying to do, but at least a JsonPath is a consistent way of addressing the particular position in a nested JSON object.

Comment: @andersschuller I want the index. I did say `string position` in my question

Comment: @atok just wondering...? Might be useful somehow

Comment: About all you can do is scan for it.  And no way to know, in the general case, which of several "duplicates" might be the one you're looking for.  As @atok implies, this isn't something you should be doing in any "real" application -- it contradicts several assumptions about how JSON is structured.

Comment: In JSON the string-position is meaningless because it can change without changing the actual data. White space can be added anywhere outside of the "".

Comment: @ZoveGames: could explain how it could be useful? A JsonObject is a map, position of keys has no meaning. Why would you like to assing one?